# Getting error in app porting

Tags: porting, bada

I am porting an app from HVGA (Bada 2.0.2 device ) to WVGA( Bada 1.2) using ecllipse( version 2.0.2 ).

For this I have done the following changes in my project

1. Project-> Properties/Bada build

   Set  Model      WVGA  and  set AutoScaling true(480x800)
2. I have  create a form of  Resolution 480x800.
3. For images I have add a folder in Resouce folder

   -> 480x800
   ->ScreenDensity-High

and place all my resources in these folder .

But my app crashes when I click the button in the app to Select more images as requirement in my app and the log show Output as Shown
Info, Installation completed.

```
0080.772,EXCEPTION,P32,T00,A125,Osp::Media::__Image::HasAlphaChannels (1547) > [E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT]
0080.774,EXCEPTION,P32,T00,A125,Osp::Media::Image::HasAlphaChannels (599) > [E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT] Propagated.
0080.851,EXCEPTION,P32,T00,A125,Osp::Media::__Image::HasAlphaChannels (1547) > [E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT]
0080.851,EXCEPTION,P32,T00,A125,Osp::Media::Image::HasAlphaChannels (599) > [E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT] Propagated.
```

I had check for this in the Bada Help but unable to find solution.Please give your suggestion to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As I see you just moved your Images (optimized for HVGA) to a new folder to use them for WVGA.

If I understand it correctly, I suggest that you with the reference of bada development documentation in your SDK (through bada IDE help system)  which specifies that what is the specific images properties for WVGA screens, change your images properties to a compatible ones (re-size them) and rebuild your project.

I think the problem will solve , we like your feedback.

best regards.

I find the reference for you mate: [Using Customized and Optimized Resources](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/topic/com.osp.appuiguide.help/html/multiple_screen/using_customized_and_optimized_resources.htm)